# Stripping non-numeric string elements

Tags: c, arrays, string, algorithm

I Have an string array having structure like this:

```
    arr[0] = "AB82374892";  
    arr[1] = "QBA9980309";
    arr[2] = "AC00098320";
```

and so on.

How do I remove each non-numeric string elements from each array element? So that the above array becomes:

```
    arr[0] = "82374892";
    arr[1] = "9980309";
    arr[2] = "00098320";
```

The objective is to obtain numeric only strings, so that dictionary level sorting can be performed efficiently.

Comment: Use [isalpha()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isalpha) to classify the characters for each char array.

Answer (score 0):

For each string, use two pointers - writer and reader.

- Iterate with the reader pointer on the array - if the element is not numeric, increase only it.
- If the element is numeric - write it and increase both pointers.

**pseudo code:**

```
writer = reader = 0
while reader < n:
   if arr[reader] is numeric:
      arr[writer++] = arr[reader++]
   else:
      reader++
```

(Don't forget to add a null terminator to each string)